# Rails: Displaying controller added error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im creating new product in controller action like this

```
product = Product.new
    product.name = params['name']
    if params['quantity']=="" then product.errors.add(:base, "Quantity must be filled") end


    if !product.save
     @product = product
     render "index"
    end
```

And im viewing errors like that

```
<% @product.errors.each do |attr, msg| %>
          <li> <%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

all errors display but only :base error does not display. How can i display them ?

The quantity column is not part of product model.

(solution) working code:

```
product.valid? 
if params['quantity']=="" then product.errors.add(:base, "error") end
if product.errors.any?
      @product = product
      render "index"
      return
else
      product.save
```

Comment: Seems like you just want a validation on the `quantity` field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not gona work, as rails removes everything from errors just before running validations. `Save` is running validations, so your custom error is removed.

I personaly  believe it is wrong to make any validations inside the controller. But if you really want to do that try:

```
product = Product.new(name: params[:name])
product.valid?
product.errors.add(:base, "Quantity must be filled") if params['quantity'].blank? then

if product.errors.any? || !product.save(false)
 @product = product
 render "index"
end
```

However this is most likely a bad idea. If quantity has anything to do with a product model, it should be validated by model. If not, it should not be added to models.errors.

You should probably try doing sth like:

```
product = Product.new(name: params[:name])
if params[:quantity].blank? || !product.save
 @product = product
 flash[:error] = "Quantity must be filled" unless params[:quantity]
 render "index"
end
```

and then add some code to handle `flash[:error]` in your view.

Comment: thank you it works, i know its not best practise.. but i want all error messages display at once.. i thought about some general Error class where i will add models errors but this is more easy.. quantity is from  other Model but i need to ensure its filled before i save product.. (both Models are saved or neither one).. i edit question with working code

Comment: If both models are to be saved at same time and they are associatied with each other, you can use autosave option on association. It will allow you to save them both at once and rails will automatically rollback both transactions if sth went wrong.

Comment: autosave is interesting i didnt know about.. but i will keep it simple for now :-)